# How to expand a PHP PDO DB connection class to execute a query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Here's our class so far:

```
class DB {
    private $DBUser = 'xxx';
    private $DBPass = 'xxx';
    private $DBServer = 'xxx';
    private $DBName = 'xxx';
    public $sql;
    public $id;

    public function __construct($sql,$id){
        $this->sql = $sql;
        $this->id = $id;
    } //end variables

    public function select() {
        try {  
            $strDSN = "mysql:host=$this->DBServer;dbname=$this->DBName;";  
            $username = $this->DBUser;
            $pass = $this->DBPass;
            $conn = new PDO($strDSN, $username, $pass);
            $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            /*return $conn;*/

            $stmt = $conn->prepare($this->sql);
            $id = $this->id;
            $stmt->execute(array('id'=>$id));
            $result = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result;

         }   
        catch (PDOException $e) {  
            echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();   
        }  
    } //end method

} //end class
```

We call it using this:

```
$db = new DB;
$result = $db->select('SELECT * FROM tbl_xxx WHERE myid = :id',$_GET['id']);
```

But I'm getting the following error:

> Warning: Missing argument 1 for DB::__construct() Warning: Missing
>   argument 2 for DB::__construct()

I'm sure the answer is a simple one, but I can't see it. What am I missing here??

Comment: You have to pass the arguments when you create a new instance from the class and not with the method select (See: `public function __construct($sql,$id){` ,  `public function select() {`) But it would make more sense if you change your code to this: `public function __construct(){` ,  `public function select($sql,$id) {`

Comment: it already says its missing an argument in the constructor. provide some. and that is confusing, the select should be the one having the arguments

Comment: @Ghost We just have to wait until the vampires comes and OP will have tunes of answers here

Comment: @Rizier123: changed the public function __construct() and public function select($sql,$id) as you suggested. However am now getting a Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1065 Query was empty message. What am I missing here..???

Answer (score 0):

I usually extend the PDO class like

```
class DB extends PDO {...}
```

Then make sure your constructor calls the parent (PDO) one with the connection string. However, once I needed to connect to the database using a separate function. This was doing:

```
// Establish the connection.
try {
    $this->str="";
    switch ($this->proto){
    case "mysql":
        $this->str = "mysql:host=$this->host;dbname=$this->db";
        break;
    default:
        throw new PDOException("Wrong protocol '$proto'");
    }

    parent::__construct($this->str,
            $this->user, $this->pw,$opts);
}catch (PDOException $e) {
    $this->last_error = $e->getMessage();
    error_log($e->getMessage());
    return false;
}
```

Also, make sure though that you do not connect every time you select! So probably you should make separate `select` and `connect` functions. Finally, instead of `select`, `delete`, etc functions I usually make a generic/base (but a bit unsafe) member which will return any query results:

```
public function send_query($query){
    $result = $this->query($query);

    if ($result === false){
        $this->last_error = $this->errorInfo();
        return false;
    }
    $ret = $result->fetchAll();
    $result->closeCursor();
    return $ret;

}
```

The above is "unsafe" because anything in `$query` string is going to run on the database. Wrapper functions should ensure that the string is properly escaped and contains no malicious code. I would suggest that you use prepared statements for all your queries but the above method should do what you ask.